# How to implement next/prev buttons on a page that uses pagination?

Tags: pagination, navigation

I have a list of items that are paginated. I now need to implement prev/next buttons on each item page that goes to the next or previous item in the entire list. This is identical to gmail's next/prev buttons when inside a message screen:
[image]

How can I implement such navigation on a page that is split up via pagination? I should add that I have custom ordering of the items on the page as well.

My technology stack is python/flask/js/jquery and postgresql.
Pagination is already implement with Flask-SqlAlchemy's pagination class.

Answer (score 1):

With :

```
obj_pagination = query.paginate(page, row_per_page)
```

you can get:

```
page_info = dict()
page_info['has_prev'] = obj_pagination.has_prev
page_info['has_next'] = obj_pagination.has_next
page_info['page'] = page
page_info['total_pages'] = obj_pagination.pages
page_info['total_pages'] = obj_pagination.pages
page_info['prev_num'] = obj_pagination.prev_num
page_info['next_num'] = obj_pagination.next_num
page_info['iter_pages'] = iter_pages(page, obj_pagination.pages)
```

Use page_info['has_prev'] to check if has previous page ( same to page_info['has_next']) ...

Comment: This looks like page pagination. I don't need page pagination, I need item traversal within a page on a paginated index.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to list a technology you are looking to do this in before you get any helpful answers. It can be done using a number of techniques on both the back and front end.

Without knowing the specific technology, it is typically done by passing a parameter that defines a few things in relation to what you mentioned. Those being page being requested (ex: page 2), whatever sort parameter has been made (ex: alphabetic), and sometimes things like number of results per page.

Wether it is handled on the front end or back end, you can either take the total results or a Postgresql like request such as using [LIMIT and Offset](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html) to get a specific set of results.

So in your case, clicking a next/previous button would pass either +1 or -1 the current page and use that multiplied by your results per page, to make the database request.

Comment: Theoretically, no but, if you want a specific answer pertaining to your technology with things like code examples then yes, it sure would help.

Comment: I just want the basic idea, I don't need the actual code.

Comment: Yup, was saving it for your response on specific technologies or if you needed the agnostic approach. Edited to generalize how to go about doing it typically.